# Pagination of Django generic ListView does not work

Tags: python, django, listview, django-class-based-views

I am new to Django and currently I am trying to integrate a webscraping backend code to a django project. While displaying my results from the webscraping, I am unable to paginate my results page which is a Django ListView. Setting paginate_by under my ListView is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Below are some of my code:

**views.py (paginate_by = 5 is not working)**

```py
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ResultsTable
    template_name = 'app/results.html'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ResultsTable.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = self.get_queryset()
        global name
        name = request.POST.get('input')
        for i in range(len(singaporews)):
            t = threading.Thread(target=Webscraper, args=[singaporews[i], name, webdriver.Chrome('/Users/angyangcheng/chromedriver')])
            allthreads.append(t)
            t.start()
        for i in allthreads:
            i.join()
        return super(PostListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.self.response_class(
            request=self.request,
            template=self.get_template_names())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        global name
        context = {
            'links' : ResultsTable.objects.all,            
            'name' : name,
            'count' : ResultsTable.objects.all().count()
        }
        return context
```

The code under my post method is mainly my webscraping logic.

results.html (pagination code)

```
   {% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="page-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="/cars?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="page-current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="/cars?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: You "circumvent" the pagination, by overriding the `get_context_data`, `get` and `post`.

Comment: Thank you. So if I put in pagination code into get_context_data, will it work?

Comment: Look at [this page](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/) to understand the `ListView` and what the various generic methods are doing. In general, when overriding a method, always call `super()` and just make modifications. Don't just override without `super()`. Your call to `super()` in `get_context_data()` is useless since you don't do anything with the result.

Comment: Note that the code you're showing here doesn't make sense. You're calling methods that aren't defined (`self.self.response_class()`) and variables that aren't defined (`singaporews`, `name`). Finally you're never calling `get_context_data()` in your `get` method.